# Missing HTML Head section from admin system->configuration->Design in magento

Tags: magento

During development i found that in system configuration->Design HTML Head section is missing.

I had gone through many tutorial but not get the solution of this problem.

I had clear the cache and perform indexing.

Disable all the install module.

I am using magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 8):

If you have added new layout in your cms section . And added Mage/Page module config.xml in local, then also add system xml there.I thing this will work for you.

local/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml